# Mental health and the work place

Tags: mental-health

Is there a registered body in the UK to which companies can join to show their commitment to consideration of employees with mental health conditions? E.g. I think company's can join Stonewall, for example, in support of diversity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Remploy](https://www.remploy.co.uk/employers) provide support and guidance to employers through services such as training, workshops, events and other resources.

> We will work with your organisation to create the conditions for success that will allow your people to flourish.

For diversity issues involving the LGBTQIA community, on top of involving [Stonewall](https://www.stonewall.org.uk), there is also [Pink Therapy](http://www.pinktherapy.com) who also have a regular newsletter available through email.

As a personal observation, some organisations *”talk the talk but don’t walk the walk”*.  It is all well and good to put on websites and flyers etc. that you support diversity and support those with mental health problems, but it doesn’t help your employees if you are not visibly supportive.  I suggest a notice board in a discrete area for reading in order for notices to be put up showing a company mental health policy detailing anyone in the workplace they can speak to in confidence, along with other organisations they can go to.

As well as the organisations I have mentioned above, the [Survivors Trust](http://thesurvivorstrust.org) also provides a [list of contacts](http://thesurvivorstrust.org/find-support) for Rape and Sexual Abuse Crisis Centres, who you can contact for leaflets, posters etc. which you can put up and make available to all employees to show commitment to support without prejudice.